# SQL CE Codefirst not generating columns for enum types

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

This is somewhat new territory for me.

I'm using MVC3 with SQL CompactEdition version 4.0 and EntityFramework version 4.1 (with CodeFirst), and MVC Scaffolding by Steven Sanderson (although I don't think that last point is relevant).

I've got several different model classes that have properties that are enums.  I find that when CodeFirst generates the schema for those tables, there is no column corresponding to those properties.

What's the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF does not support enums, plain and simple.

The easiest workaround is having a mapped property that converts the enum to/from a `string` or `int` (depending on how you want to store the values)

The alternative, of course, is choosing a more mature framework (NHibernate is the one I like, but there are others)

Comment: So define the model object with two properties, one of which is a string or int with automatic getter/setter, and the other is the enum with a getter/setter doing the mapping?  Or can I simply define one property that is the enum with a getter/setter mapping to an explicitly defined string or int backing store? (i.e., does EF work only with properties, or can it work with the underlying fields?)

Comment: @DaveHanna: AFAIK, EF works with properties. As long as you expose something it recognizes, you can define the backing storage any way you see fit.